# Which data structure should I use to keep mutable objects sorted?

Tags: c#, data-structures

I have a bunch of objects that look somewhat like this:

```
public class MyObject
    {
        public DateTime SortProperty { get; set; }
        // ...
    }
```

The SortProperty can change, and there can be a lot of `MyObject`s. Insertion is done once, but the `SortProperty`s can change often (I guess I would need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for this and hook it up to a new sort(?)). While accessing the objects, the most important requirements are to be able to 1) access the objects in a sorted manner and 2) access both the object *before* and *after* the given object. So the question is, what kind of a data structure should I use to accomplish this?

So far I've just been googling around, and have considered `SortedList<TKey, TValue>` and `SortedSet`. Problem with the list is that it doesn't accept duplicate keys, while the problem with the set is that I'm unsure about being able to accomplish requirement 2 with it.

Am I missing something obvious or are there some other data structures that would better fit my requirements?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'the list doesn't accept duplicate keys'? As long as distict objects are included, no problems should occur.

Comment: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx: "Key objects must be immutable as long as they are used as keys in the SortedList<TKey, TValue>. Every key in a SortedList<TKey, TValue> must be unique."